# Inserting hour:minute entry in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using python with SQLAlchemy. I simply cannot insert a hour:minute pair. See the example:

SQL query 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_time (time_col _time)
```

(this works fine)

SQL query 2:

```
INSERT INTO test_time(time_col) VALUES('17:30');
```

This fails and shows the error:

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test_time(time_col) VALUES('17:30');
                                               ^ 
DETAIL:  ARRAY value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

I have no idea what `dimension information` could be. But adding `{}` in any form I could think of didn't help either.

What is the correct form to insert a _time value in PostgreSQL with an SQL query?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver : I've checked my code, the comma was added by mistake, I"ve corrected it here. But I don't want to add an array, I want a single time entry.

Comment: You probably want `time` not `_time` (which is an array of time values)

Comment: For some reason [unclear to me] PostgreSQL accepts `_time` and that produces the problem. Change to the type to `time`.

Comment: @TheImpaler `_time` is an alias type for `time[]` because `[]` is invalid in an identifier (a type name) the Postgres devs decided to internally use the data type prefixed with an underscore. So `_int` is `int[]`. This isn't the first time people are using an "underscore type" and are surprised. As this isn't really documented in the manually (it's an internal thing), I wonder how and why people decide to use them.

Comment: @TheImpaler yep, that is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_time (time_col, _time)` is wrong and will not complete as there is no type information for the columns.  Unless you meant `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_time (time_col  _time)`,  It would be better done as `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_time (time_col time[])` to make it clearer you are working with an array. Update with the actual table definition. The error is indication that `time_col` is an `ARRAY` type so you would  need to enter as an array e.g. `ARRAY['17:30'::time]`.

**UPDATE**

`_time` is an alias for the array type`time[]`. If you just want a `time` field then:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_time (time_col time );`